# Nvim relative numbers line jumping is deleting lines instead of jumping around

Tags: neovim

I am new to nvim, but something isn't functions as it seems it should be. When I try to enter something such as '5j', the cursor jumps places but also deletes lines, it doesn't remove what was typed onto a given line, rather it moves the line up and so the length of code is now shortened in terms of number of lines. If I try to use say '5k' then it says 'Argument Required'.

Looking for a possible explanation

I have both relative line numbers and line numbers on.

I went back through all my configurations to no avail, I had thought this feature was an out-of-the-box feature, that is the movement not the removal of lines. I did all my configurations using Lua.

Comment: What if you start with a fresh version of Vim/Neovim `vim -u NONE -U NONE -i NONE` or `vim --clean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`5j` and `5k` are normal mode commands, as such, they are supposed to be typed *in normal mode*.

But you seem to be typing those in command-line mode: `:5j` and `:5k`, where they have a completely different meaning.

| Command | Meaning in normal mode | Meaning in command-line mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `5j` | Move cursor 5 lines down | Join line 6 with line 5 |
| `5k` | Move cursor 5 lines up | With an argument, say `:5ka`, place mark `a` at line 5 |

See `:help j` and `:help k` for normal mode `j` and `k`.

See `:help :j` and `:help :k` for command-line mode `:j` and `:k`.

See `:help 02.2` for a very gentle introduction to modal editing.

My advice, slow down on the configuring and double down on the learning: `:help user-manual`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now